# ASP.NET 5 - accessing a cookie in the response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET 5, you can access cookies sent in the request quite easily:

```
 var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
 var cookie = request.Cookies["somecookie"];
```

However, suppose that during a request, the cookie was updated by some other part of the application. In that case there would be an outdated cookie in the request, and the newly update cookie would be in the current response.

I would like to ensure that I always inspect the "latest" cookie, so therefore I'd like if a cookie is present in the response, to use that version, overriding the cookie in the request. But here is the thing, when I want to access the cookie in the Response - there is no API to do so?

```
 var response = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
 response.Cookies.?
```

How to achieve this? I wanted to avoid managing this state elsewhere if possible, and it seems I should be able to do this..

Comment: There is only 1 cookie server side. When you send it in the response it is replaced and you get it back on the next request. You wouldn't need to get it out of the response because you would still be server side.

Comment: Unless he's trying to inspect the value of the cookie that's being sent to the client by some code earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: @rossipedia - yes exactly that... the cookie may have been set earlier in the pipeline and it holds the state. I dont want to inspect the cookie in the request if the there is "newer" state present in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this API is coming anytime soon, so in the end, I had to rework various middleware, to change the way cookie state is managed. I now hold my state in an object instance (DTO) scoped to current http request. If any part of my application needs to access the current state it has that object injected (DI). Finally, I have some middleware that manages the cookie. The middleware restores the DTO from the cookie at the start of a request, and writes the DTO to a cookie during the response. I make sure that this middleware is the only thing to ever touch the cookie itself, and everythign that needs to inspect the state just has the DTO injected.